# mux-player-react streaming loop video loads on every loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mux-video

I'm using mux-player-react on a next.js site to implement a background looped movie ([agobay.com](https://agobay.com)). Unfortunately the video reloads after each loop. On slower connection, it starts first with a poor quality version and reloads the good one later. But this happens on each loop again. How can I prevent this (caching video?)

thanks for help

```
 <MuxPlayer className={styles.videoMob}
                 playbackId={'xxxx'}
                 streamType="on-demand"
                 loop
                 muted
                 autoPlay
      />
```